# How to merge mesh grid points from two rectangles in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to merge the mesh grids formed at two different (adjoining) rectangles. Following is the pictorial representation of the rectangle:

[image]

I can create the mesh grids of the individual rectangles. For example for the green rectangle, using the following code snippet, we can create a mesh grid.

```html
xvalues = np.array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
yvalues = np.array([6, 8, 10, 12])
x, y = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)
positions = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
theGridPoints = (np.array(positions)).T
```

I can make the grid points for the blue rectangle too. However, I'm unable to join them inside a single object. I tried to join them as the sum of `position1` and `position2`. I get the value error on the console as:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (.,.) (.,.)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bx, by = np.mgrid[0:2, 0:5]
gx, gy = np.mgrid[0:10, 5:12]

bp = np.vstack((bx.ravel(), by.ravel()))
gp = np.vstack((gx.ravel(), gy.ravel()))

points = np.hstack((bp, gp)).T

# full grid
plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], c='orange', s=200)
# green rectangle
plt.scatter(gp.T[:,0], gp.T[:,1], c='green', s=50)
# blue rectangle
plt.scatter(bp.T[:,0], bp.T[:,1], c='blue', s=50)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. To add more, every grid points (green and blue) contain a data and I want to plot a 3-D surface plot with it. For the full grid, I'd do:

`fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x=y=np.arange(0,12,2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = gridValue.reshape(X.shape)
cset = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('gridValue ')`

How can I plot only for green and blue parts (removing the blank part)?

Comment: Instead of `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)` you should try `ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)`.

Comment: I did
`fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x=np.arange(0,10,1)
y=np.arange(0,12,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = gridValue.reshape(X.shape)
cset = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('σ ')
fig.colorbar(cset, shrink=0.5, aspect =5)
plt.show()`
I get: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 80 into shape (12,10)`

Comment: @Scotty1-  `pcolormesh` is not the solution in my case. Doing it, I get `AttributeError: 'QuadMesh' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'`
The reason of the `ValueError` is that I've 80 points to plot and the grid is formed of 120 points. How can I exclude the grid points that do not have any data (the blank space in the figure of accepted answer)?

Comment: @santobedi I'm having a little trouble following the code in the comments. Maybe it deserves a new question for the 3D case? Or just edit this with the new code so we can copy and paste it

Comment: @santobedi `pcolormesh` is a pseudo-color plot. That means it plots a 2d-surface which is colored. Thus you can't use `projection='3d'`. Try `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`. If you want a 3d-projection, you need to use another plotting method. Excluding points depends on how you value data array is shaped. In general I'd recommend making the value data array the same shape as the grid point array, setting values not to plot to `0` and then mask both arrays with `mask = value_data_array == 0` `ax.pcolormesh(X[mask], Y[mask], Z[mask], cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)`

Comment: @santobedi you could try with masked arrays but apparently `plot_surface` just ignores the mask... the best you could do is to set missing values to something invalid like `0` but you'd still get them in the plot. See e.g. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/487 (last update is from 2015... don't think it the proposal got anywhere)

Comment: @filippo  How can we fix the gap/space between the grid points? For example ; 
`bx, by = np.mgrid[0:2, 0:5]
gx, gy = np.mgrid[0:10, 5:12]`

Here, the space between any two grid points is one unit. How can I make the space as 2 units?

Comment: @filippo I fixed it with changing the coordinate system. Is there any syntax for it in python? For example, I changed the range of x-axis from 8 to 4.

Comment: @santobedi `np.mgrid` uses a slice-like syntax so you can do `np.mgrid[0:2:2, 0:5:2]` or use `np.meshgrid` with `np.arange(start, stop, step)` to generate coordinates or even with `np.linspace`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join/merge multiple `np.ndarray`, they need to be of the same `shape`. So you the number of `xvalues` of the blue rectangle need to be equal to the number of `xvalues` of the green rectangle. Same for the `yvalues`.
Here is a short example:

```
xvalues_b = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
yvalues_b = np.array([0, 1*5/3, 2*5/3, 3*5/3])
x_b, y_b = np.meshgrid(xvalues_b, yvalues_b)
positions_b = np.vstack([x_b.ravel(), y_b.ravel()])
theGridPoints_b = (np.array(positions_b)).T
positions_gb = np.concatenate([positions, positions_b])
```