# Generating 3-D surface plot with data from different sized grid points in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I learned to merge mesh grid points from two rectangles in python from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330251/how-to-merge-mesh-grid-points-from-two-rectangles-in-python) question. The merged grid points are:

[image]

Here each grid points contains their respective values and I want to plot a 3-D surface plot of it. For the full grid (without blank spot), I'd write the following code:

```html
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x=np.arange(0,10,1)
y=np.arange(0,12,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print (Y)
Z = gridValue.reshape(X.shape)
cset = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False)
ax.clabel(cset, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('σ ')
fig.colorbar(cset, shrink=0.5, aspect =5)
plt.show()
```

When I try to plot the grid values (80 points) with above code, I get an obvious error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 80 into shape (12,10)
```

I'm expecting the following figure (not exactly but similar way) as the final 3-D surface plot:

[image]

How can I draw a 3-D surface plot is my situation?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I tried to plot using the following code snippet:

```html
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x1=np.arange(0,2,1)
x2 = np.arange(0,10,1)
y1 =np.arange(0,5,1)
y2=np.arange(5,12,1)
Y1, X1 = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)
Y2, X2 = np.meshgrid(x2,y2)
gridValue1 = gridValue[:10]
gridValue2 = gridValue[10:]
Z1 = gridValue1.reshape(X1.shape)
Z2 = gridValue2.reshape(X2.shape)
cset1 = ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False)
cset2 = ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False)
ax.clabel(cset1, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.clabel(cset2, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('σ ')
plt.show()
```

I got following figure with this code:

[image]

Now the problem is to illustrate the figure. The color code (red color for high value, blue color for low value) is not valid any longer. Because the `gridValues` of blue gird points (in the first figure) are high, so most of them should have red color in the surface plot. So merging two individual 3-D surface plots is not the solution to my problem. Any help, please!

Comment: `gridValue` is missing.

Comment: @Scotty1- The above code is just a code snippet. The error is not due to missing `gridValue`. It's calculated in different lines of codes.

Comment: added the colorbar scaling in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `gridValue` array is larger than your meshgrid with `(12,10)` you need to interpolate `gridValue` to the correct shape.
In your case, since I guess that you want to plot the shown shapes with `80` points, you need to construct an array for `gridValue` with the shape of the meshgrid and then distribute your 80 grid values to the correct positions of the `gridValue` array with shape `(12,10)`. How you can do the distribution fully depends on the information that you have, thus unluckily I can't help you with that. But for example considering a y-sorted sequential distribution of the blue and green grids:

```
gridValue_new = np.zeros_like(X)
gridValue_new[:, 0] = gridValue[:12]
gridValue_new[:, 1] = gridValue[12:24]
gridValue_new.reshape(-1)[:8, 2:] = gridValue[24:]
```

The first two ligns distributing points could also be rewritten using `reshape()`.

If you want to plot it in 2d, use `pcolormesh`.
For 3d-plotting, using `ax.plot_surface()` will fit your needs.
If you want to plot both grids in one axis, do the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 10, 1), np.arange(0, 12, 1))
X1 = X[5:, :]
Y1 = Y[5:, :]
X2 = X[0:5, 0:2]
Y2 = Y[0:5, 0:2]
Z1 = np.random.rand(7, 10)  # generating some random grid values
Z2 = np.random.rand(5, 2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1)
ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2)
```

To get the correct colorbar, get the min/max values of your array:

```
vmin = gridValue.min()
vmax = gridValue.max()
```

and pass both as argument to `plot_surface()`:

```
cset1 = ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
cset2 = ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

So your full code will look like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x1=np.arange(0,2,1)
x2 = np.arange(0,10,1)
y1 =np.arange(0,5,1)
y2=np.arange(5,12,1)
Y1, X1 = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)
Y2, X2 = np.meshgrid(x2,y2)
gridValue1 = gridValue[:10]
gridValue2 = gridValue[10:]
Z1 = gridValue1.reshape(X1.shape)
Z2 = gridValue2.reshape(X2.shape)
vmin = gridValue.min()
vmax = gridValue.max()
cset1 = ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
cset2 = ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth =0, antialiased = False, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax.clabel(cset1, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.clabel(cset2, fontsize=9, inline=1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('σ ')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to merge two 3-D surface plots into one? In that case, I can plot individual 3-D surface plots for the green dots and blue dots.

Comment: Sure, you can just do `cset1 = ax.pcolormesh(X1, Y1, Z2, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)` and then `cset2 = ax.pcolormesh(X2, Y2, Z2, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)`

Comment: Just one more hint: `pcolormesh` plots the information **between** the points specified in the meshgrid, thus your plot will always be one row and column smaller than your meshgrid. To avoid this, add one column and row to `X`, `Y` and `Z`. For `Z` it is the easiest to either copy the first or last row/column.